# React inline style doesn't affect my custom component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I have a custom component where I need to add it margin-top in in of my uses. I tried `<MyComponent style={{ marginTop: '10px' }}>` and also

```
const myStyle = { marginTop: '10px' };
`<MyComponent style={myStyle}>`;
```

And it both don't work.
When I do the same in the same file for a simple `<div>` (e.g. `<div style={{ marginTop: '10px' }}>` and `<div style={myStyle}>` it works as expected.

Maybe it is important to mention that the wrapping element of my custom component (`<MyComponent/>`) is a `styled-component`.

Would appreciate anyway to fix it or make it work. Thanks!

Comment: You are using class components or functional components?

Comment: If you're using styled component than why you need inline styles mate ?

Comment: @MaheerAli A functional component

Comment: @CodeManiac The component I built is being reuse in different sections and so each time it is aligned differently, but now that I write it maybe I can allow passing a marginTop prop to it. Thou I still wonder why it doesn't work

Comment: You can simply pass props and accordingly have the css. this is why we use styled component

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `style` prop will be just be like any other prop for a custom component. You need to take the `style` prop given to `MyComponent` and add it to the `style` prop of one of the elements inside `MyComponent`.

**Example**

```js
function MyComponent(props) {
  return <div style={props.style}>MyComponent</div>;
}

function MyBrokenComponent() {
  return <div>MyBrokenComponent</div>;
}

function App() {
  const style = { marginTop: "10px", backgroundColor: "green" };

  return (
    <div>
      <MyBrokenComponent style={style} />
      <MyComponent style={style} />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're using [**Styled-components**](https://www.styled-components.com/) library you can pass props and based on props you can set styles

```
const MyComponent = styled.div`
  margin-top: ${props => props.marginTop || 'initial'}
`

<MyComponent marginTop = '20px' />
```

Answer (score 0):

`<MyComponent style={myStyle}>` is a react component and then you pass `style` it will be passed a normal `prop`. Inside style are applied to html elements not React Components.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<div>App</div>);
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<React.Fragment><App style={{color:"blue"}}/><div style={{color:"blue"}}>Element</div></React.Fragment>,document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```